# Migrating azure-pipelines.yaml to separate repo, but running on code of other repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Ultimately, I'm trying to do this:

- Move `azure-pipelines.yaml` and associated templates out of the code repository (`code-repo`).
- Move them into a separate dedicated repository (`pipeline-repo`).
- Have the pipeline look at the config for the pipeline in `pipeline-repo`, but run the pipeline on the code in the `code-repo`.

I'm referring the following documentation:

- [Use other repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories): this one refers to "templates in other repositories," but I'm trying to remove any pipeline configs so the `code-repo` is just purely application code... and the `Dockerfile`.
- [Define a `repositories` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource)

For testing, I have this simple `test.yaml`:

```
# Triggers when PR is created due to branch policies
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code-repo
    type: git
    name: code-repo

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Testing
  displayName: Test stage
  jobs:
  - job: ParallelA
    steps:
    - bash: echo Hello from parallel job A
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

When I create a PR on `code-repo`, it is triggering the pipeline, which is to say branch policies are configured to refer to that pipeline. I do get the print out the `Hello from parallel job A` print out.

But I don't see in the run logs it pulling `code-repo`.

I do see the following, however:
[image]

My actual PR pipeline would look something like this:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code-repo
    type: git
    name: code-repo

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

pool:
  vmIMage: $(vmImageName)

stages:
- template: templates/build/buildStage.yaml
...
```

Testing that, it confirms that it isn't running on the `code-repo` PR, but the `pipeline-repo` so everything fails.

So it is unclear to me what I need to do from here to get the pipeline to run on the PR code from `code-repo`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have it sorted out, at least some of my stages are now succeeding.

I came across [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) which informed me of `checkout`.

So in addition to doing something like:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code-repo
    type: git
    name: code-repo
```

Then you need to add a `step` called `checkout` like the following:

```
# Triggers when PR is created due to branch policies
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code-repo
    type: git
    name: code-repo

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Testing
  displayName: Test stage
  jobs:
  - job: ParallelA
    steps:
    - checkout: code-repo
    - task: task1
    - task: task2
```

The `checkout` should set the context for the subsequent steps.

Comment: question: Why did you move pipeline definitions out of the code repo?